# How to pass redux state in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a app which uses react and redux for state management. Here I got a problem with it. I have a component called `choose-address` in which user selects address and then press button and gets redirected to the `cart` page this works fine till here  but after cart it goes to `checkout-summery`. and in this component I need the `addressId` which user have selected in `choose-address` component  but the problem is if I refresh the `checkout-summery` page the `addressid` goes back to `undefined`. I am unable to figure out how to fix this. Any help would be great.

> addressActions

```
///address ui
export const chooseAddress = addressId => ({
  type: types.CHOOSE_ADDRESS,
  addressId
});
```

> addressUiReducer

```
const initialState = {
  addressChosen: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.CHOOSE_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        addressChosen: action.addressId
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

> choose-address.jsx

```
 <Grid className="choose-address">
          {addressList.map(address => (
            <AddresListItem
              address={address}
              deleteAddress={deleteAddress}
              chooseAddress={chooseAddress}
              uiState={uiState}
            />
          ))}
          <Grid className="margin15" container justify="center">
            <Grid xs={8}>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                title={"+ ADD NEW ADDRESS"}
                onClick={() => {
                  history.push("/add-new-address");
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          {uiState.addressChosen !== null && (
            <Button
              title={"Continue"}
              onClick={() => {
                history.push("/cart");
              }}
            />
          )}
```

> chooseAddressContainer.jsx

```
class ChooseAddressContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserAddress();
  }
  render() {
    const {
      addressList,
      deleteAddress,
      history,
      chooseAddress,
      uiState
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid className="global-padding">
        <ChooseAddress
          history={history}
          chooseAddress={chooseAddress}
          deleteAddress={deleteAddress}
          addressList={addressList}
          uiState={uiState}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

const mapstateToProps = state => {
  return {
    addressList: state.address.data.addressMultiple.addressList,
    uiState: state.address.ui
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapstateToProps,
  {
    getUserAddress,
    deleteAddress,
    chooseAddress
  }
)(ChooseAddressContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux persist, which will preserve your redux store over refresh.

[Check out this link.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of data consistency.

To keep data persisted which will be used throughout the app flow and holds after you refresh/reload the app, redux-persist is the option.

Here is the [link of the article](https://medium.com/@dharacharolap/get-rid-of-data-consistency-with-the-redux-persist-86559e96de32) having simple but detailed steps to integrate & use the package in your existing app.

Hope this will help you out.